# How can I change query params without a controller in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a callback from a library which returns data that I need to use to update query params. The problem is that this callback has no reference to any Ember structure or data. Is there a way to get access to the current controller to do `controller.set(param, value)` or perhaps a way of doing `Ember.transitionTo({param: value})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Ember to update the URL, you can do it from anywhere and Ember will detect the change and update the query parameters on the corresponding controller automatically. So in your case, just update the URL and Ember will know what to do. I was able to do this and it worked fine:

```
window.location.search = '?key=newvalue';
```

Comment: This refreshes the whole page, which really doesn't help the case in most Ember applications.